# How to validate react-select dropdown using use form hook in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, yup, react-hook-form

I am new to yup validation, and I am populating the react-select dropdown with the below options. and now when I click on one button trying to validate if any value is selected or not. but it is not validating. any help is much appreciated.

```
const options = [
        { value: 'active', label: 'Active' },
        { value: 'inactive', label: 'In Active' },
        { value: 'deleted', label: 'Delete' },
 ];

<Select
  defaultValue={options[0]}
  isSearchable={false}
  className="react-dropdown"
  onChange={statusDropdownHandleChange}
  classNamePrefix="dropdown"
  options={options}
  name="status"
  {...register("status")}
/>


let schema = yup.object().shape({
    status: yup.object().shape({
      label: yup.string().required("status is required"),
      value: yup.string().required("status is required")
    })
 });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The validation should be working but if you are using `Select` with `react-hook-form` directly, you will hit the error/value undefined when choosing value/submitting form as `Select` doesn't expose input's ref. Therefore, you need to wrap `Select` with [Controller](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started) to register the component.

For validating the form, there is one more case to handle if you allow `isClearable` in `Select` where the value will be `null` instead of `{label: undefined, value: undefined}` so there is a need to add `.nullable()` and `.required()` at the end of status's validation.

**validation**

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  status: yup
    .object()
    .shape({
      label: yup.string().required("status is required (from label)"),
      value: yup.string().required("status is required")
    })
    .nullable() // for handling null value when clearing options via clicking "x"
    .required("status is required (from outter null check)")
});
```

**form with react-select**

```js
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <Controller
        name="status"
        control={control}
        render={({ field }) => (
        <Select
            // defaultValue={options[0]}
            {...field}
            isClearable
            isSearchable={false}
            className="react-dropdown"
            classNamePrefix="dropdown"
            options={options}
        />
        )}
    />
    <p>{errors.status?.message || errors.status?.label.message}</p>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

[Here is the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-lederberg-w10v0?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mic. I spent a lot of time on it.

Comment: I had never valued a StackOverflow response this much. There is a very vague description on the react-hook-form official site ( [link](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started) ) "... If the component doesn't expose input's ref, ..." and your response to this question made it all very clear to me. I had spent many hours in this. Thank you for your kindness. God bless you!

Comment: and if select is multipe ? will it be array instead of object

Comment: is there a way to return only the value?

Comment: Are you sure `react-select` doesn't expose input ref?. You can use both `register` or `Controller`.

Comment: can you put input border error state for react-select